# How Do I set login path in razor pages core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
Why I am getting,  The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter 'value')

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                });
ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter 'value')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your `Login`  razor model structure in project?

Comment: it is not a controller it is a .cshtml page

Comment: it is under pages folder

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes I do

Comment: The error you are getting it should encounter if you ommit `"/"` like "login" but "/login" should resolve your issue.

Comment: Would you kindly share your login page details, you can exclude your sensitive information if there any.

Comment: I did @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: Yes I am checking, as screenshot given so need time to investigate, you have higher point here in so still you have included screenshots bro and you are developer. Who else would  I explain bro.

Comment: What kind of authetication are you using? Is it dientity or anything else.

Comment: not sure still learning, I want to use cookie one.

Comment: I without "/" only it throw the exception. But you said you put "/Login"

Comment: You can use `AddRazorPagesOptions` to define your login convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I am getting,  The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter
> 'value')

In my test, I can reproduce the issue once I ommit the "/" from the login path. As you can see the error I reproduce:

[image]

I have tried in following way:

Login Convention I set:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
});
```

Cookie Authentication Configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                });
```

Middleware I am using:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
using Maqta.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
    AddCookie("Cookie",options => {options.LoginPath = "/login";});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(DbConnection => new SqlConnection(

builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HrSoultion")));
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

Then in index page 

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie")]
```

Comment: If you don't put `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie")]` it wouldn't throw that error. It will only throw the error if you ommit "/" from your login path.

Comment: By putting [Authorize] attribute in Index page it will restrict access and this is what it does.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron it di work with me bro.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i send you request in linkedin bro.

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. Anyway, the way I debug and investigate is correct as well.